# bosh deploy get uninitialized constant Fog::AWS::CredentialFetcher (NameError)

Tags: initialization, cloud-foundry, nameerror, fog, cf-bosh

I am try deploy stcemcells by use bosh micro.

I have a stemcell bosh-stemcell-2719.2-openstack-kvm-centos-go_agent.tgz and a deploy file micro_bosh.yml

they are in same folder "my-micro-deployment"
my deploy file micro_bosh.yml's content is in follow

```
---
name: microbosh-openstack

logging: 
  level: DEBUG 

network: 
  type: dynamic
  vip: 172.24.10.131
  cloud_properties: 
    net_id: 9e5a6fd5-fa2e-48da-94ce-f85337bc2451

resources: 
  persistent_disk: 20000
  cloud_properties: 
    instance_type: m1.small 

cloud: 
  plugin: openstack 
  properties: 
    openstack: 
      auth_url: http://172.24.10.128:5000/v2.0 
      username: demo 
      api_key: openstack 
      tenant: demo 
      default_security_groups: [bosh] 
      default_key_name: demokey 
      private_key: /home/roger/my-micro-deployment/demokey.pem 

apply_spec: 
  properties: 
    director: 
      max_threads: 2
  hm: 
    resurrector_enabled: true 
  ntp: 
    - time.asia.apple.com
```

then I execute command

```
bosh micro deployment micorbosh.yml
```

then I execute command

```
bosh micro deploy bosh-stemcell-2719.2-openstack-kvm-centos-go_agent.tgz
```

after the above commands be executed I get the error

```
`/home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/auto_scaling.rb:4:in `<class:AutoScaling>': uninitialized constant Fog::AWS::CredentialFetcher (NameError)
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/auto_scaling.rb:3:in `<module:AWS>'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/auto_scaling.rb:2:in `<module:Fog>'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/auto_scaling.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-1.27.0/lib/fog/aws.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-1.27.0/lib/fog.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/bosh-registry-1.2922.0/lib/bosh/registry.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/bosh-registry-1.2922.0/bin/bosh-registry:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/roger/bin/bosh-registry:23:in `load'
from /home/roger/bin/bosh-registry:23:in `<main>'
bosh-registry -c /tmp/d20150414-92091-1rc0vqs/bosh_registry_yml20150414- 92091-9n3izm` failed, exit status=1``
```

can any one give me some advice?

thanks in advance it block me 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue recently as well on my MacOS machine (everything works fine on my Linux machine). I haven't yet gone deep into it but as a workaround you can place the

```
require_relative('.')
```

string at the beginning of the `/home/roger/.gem/ruby/gems/fog-aws-0.1.2/lib/fog/aws/auto_scaling.rb`.

Comment: I have solved this issue by freezing aws-fog gem to version `<= 0.1.1`. Here is a PR for this https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/834.